# Optimizing layout/bitmaps/database with ASYNC or another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap

As a beginner I have some questions about optimizing my application speed. I'm building a simple quiz app there I have an sqlite database inside with some information. With that information I'm generating my questions in quiz page.

It was working pretty fine and fast until I fixed some buttons/background in sketch and use them. Now it's working much more slower and I'm getting error messages at logcat like "Skipped xxx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." I have searched on google for a while and found out that the bitmaps are slowing down my application. Have read about async and using a new thread to make it run faster.

As a solution I have resized some of my bitmaps, but then I'm getting less quality in my design, so I decided to fix it. I have googled some more about loading my layout with async or a new thread but didn't really find out how/where to do it. What makes me confused is that I don't know if it's to load layout with a new thread is the best solution or to load other processes with new thread. Need some recommendation about how to optimize my app. Here is my code, at least the quiz page that is slowest. I'm not really sure what to optimize there with a new thread. Under a question it's just countdowntimer that is running, and when next clicked countdowntimer starts over and the gui updates with the new question.

My quizpage code:

```
public class QuizPage extends ActionBarActivity
{

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);     
    Cursor kommunCrs, lanCrs, riktCrs;        
    ArrayList<Kommuner> kommunLista = new ArrayList<Kommuner>();
    ArrayList<Lan> lanLista = new ArrayList<Lan>();
    ArrayList<Riktnummer> riktLista = new ArrayList<Riktnummer>();    
    ArrayList<Fragar> fragaLista = new ArrayList<Fragar>();      

    Fragar svList = new Fragar();                            
    Fragar frageObj = new Fragar();                          

    int buttonRaknare = 0;

    CountDownTimer cd;                    
    long millisLeft;                      
    long totalMillis = 10100;              
    int pBarProgress;                       

    TextView pageNr, fraga, cdText;                

    RadioButton valA, valB, valC, valD;    
    RadioGroup rg;                         
    Button avsluta, nasta;                
    ProgressBar pBar;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_page);

    checkDB();                                  // Checking the DB
    getCursorData();                            // Getting data to cursors
    setCrsdataList();                           // Setting cursor data to lists
    setViewElements();                          // Set textview, buttons etc.
    setButtonListeners();
    getNastaFragaData();                        // Refresing the gui with the next question
    startCountdownTimer(totalMillis, false);    // Countdowntimer starts
}


private void getCursorData()
{
    kommunCrs = dbHelper.getDatabase().query("Kommuner ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 50", new String[]{"kommun_id", "kommun_namn", "kommun_lan", "kommun_befolkning"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    lanCrs = dbHelper.getDatabase().query("Lan ORDER BY RANDOM()", new String[]{"lan_namn", "lan_befolkning", "lan_antal_kommun", "lan_yta", "lan_id"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    riktCrs = dbHelper.getDatabase().query("Riktnummer ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 50", new String[]{"riktnr", "riktnr_omrade", "riktnr_id"}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

private void setCrsdataList()
{
    if (kommunCrs.getCount() != 0 && lanCrs.getCount() != 0 && riktCrs.getCount() != 0) {
        kommunCrs.moveToFirst();
        lanCrs.moveToFirst();
        riktCrs.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < kommunCrs.getCount(); i++) {
            Kommuner tempKommun = new Kommuner();

            tempKommun.setKommun_namn(kommunCrs.getString(kommunCrs.getColumnIndex("kommun_namn")));
            tempKommun.setKommun_lan(kommunCrs.getString(kommunCrs.getColumnIndex("kommun_lan")));
            tempKommun.setKommun_befolkning(kommunCrs.getString(kommunCrs.getColumnIndex("kommun_befolkning")));
            tempKommun.setKommun_id(kommunCrs.getInt(kommunCrs.getColumnIndex("kommun_id")));

            kommunLista.add(tempKommun);
            kommunCrs.moveToNext();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lanCrs.getCount(); i++) {
            Lan tempLan = new Lan();

            tempLan.setLan_namn(lanCrs.getString(lanCrs.getColumnIndex("lan_namn")));
            tempLan.setLan_befolkning(lanCrs.getString(lanCrs.getColumnIndex("lan_befolkning")));
            tempLan.setLan_antal_kommun(lanCrs.getString(lanCrs.getColumnIndex("lan_antal_kommun")));
            tempLan.setLan_yta(lanCrs.getString(lanCrs.getColumnIndex("lan_yta")));
            tempLan.setLan_id(lanCrs.getInt(lanCrs.getColumnIndex("lan_id")));

            lanLista.add(tempLan);
            lanCrs.moveToNext();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < riktCrs.getCount(); i++) {
            Riktnummer tempRiktnr = new Riktnummer();

            tempRiktnr.setRiktnr(riktCrs.getString(riktCrs.getColumnIndex("riktnr")));
            tempRiktnr.setRiktnr_omrade(riktCrs.getString(riktCrs.getColumnIndex("riktnr_omrade")));
            tempRiktnr.setRiktnr_id(riktCrs.getInt(riktCrs.getColumnIndex("riktnr_id")));

            riktLista.add(tempRiktnr);
            riktCrs.moveToNext();
        }

        //Generating my questions here and taking in to a list
        fragaLista = frageObj.slumpaFragor(kommunLista, lanLista, riktLista);


        Collections.shuffle(fragaLista);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finns ingen data i databasen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void getNastaFragaData()
{
    fraga.setText(fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getFraga());
    valA.setText(fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getSvarArr().get(0).toString());
    valB.setText(fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getSvarArr().get(1).toString());
    valC.setText(fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getSvarArr().get(2).toString());
    valD.setText(fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getSvarArr().get(3).toString());
    pageNr.setText(Integer.toString(buttonRaknare+1) + "/20");
}

private void rattSvarCheck()
{
    if (valA.isChecked())
    {
        fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).userInput = valA.getText().toString();

        if (valA.getText().hashCode() == fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getRattSvar().hashCode())
        {
            svList.antalRattSvar++;
        }
        else
        {
            svList.antalFelSvar++;
        }
    }
    else if (valB.isChecked())
    {
        fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).userInput = valB.getText().toString();

        if (valB.getText().hashCode() == fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getRattSvar().hashCode())
        {
            svList.antalRattSvar++;
        }
        else
        {
            svList.antalFelSvar++;
        }
    }
    else if (valC.isChecked())
    {
        fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).userInput = valC.getText().toString();

        if (valC.getText().hashCode() == fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getRattSvar().hashCode())
        {
            svList.antalRattSvar++;
        }
        else
        {
            svList.antalFelSvar++;
        }
    }
    else if (valD.isChecked())
    {
        fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).userInput = valD.getText().toString();

        if (valD.getText().hashCode() == fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).getRattSvar().hashCode())
        {
            svList.antalRattSvar++;
        }
        else
        {
            svList.antalFelSvar++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fragaLista.get(buttonRaknare).userInput = "";
        svList.antalTomtSvar++;
    }
}

private void resultatToDatabas()
{
    dbHelper.resultatToDatabas(svList.antalRattSvar, svList.antalFelSvar, svList.antalTomtSvar);
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),QuizResultat.class);
    i.putExtra("rslist", fragaLista);
    i.putExtra("sl", svList);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}

private void startCountdownTimer(long millis, final boolean isResume)
{
    if (!isResume)
    {
        pBar.setProgress(100);
        pBar.setProgressDrawable(pBar.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nypbar));
    }
    else
    {
        pBar.setProgress(pBarProgress);
        pBar.setProgressDrawable(pBar.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nypbar));

        if (pBar.getProgress() < 55 && pBar.getProgress() > 23 )
        {
            pBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFB800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        else if (pBar.getProgress() < 23)
        {
            pBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFE71000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }

    int callInterval = 100;

    cd = new CountDownTimer(millis, callInterval)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            millisLeft = millisUntilFinished;
            pBarProgress = pBar.getProgress();

            int secondsRemaining = (int) millisUntilFinished / 100;
            float fraction = millisUntilFinished / (float) totalMillis;

            // progress bar is based on scale of 1 to 100;
            pBar.setProgress((int) (fraction * 100));

            cdText.setText(String.format("%2.1f", secondsRemaining / 10.0, Integer.toString(secondsRemaining)));

            if (pBar.getProgress() < 55 && pBar.getProgress() > 23 )
            {
                pBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFB800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            else if (pBar.getProgress() < 23)
            {
                pBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFE71000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {

            nasta.performClick();
        }
    }.start();
}

// Deklarera knappar, textview osv.
private void setViewElements()
{
    pageNr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pageNumberTxt);
    fraga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragaTxt);

    valA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valAbtn);
    valB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valBbtn);
    valC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valCbtn);
    valD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.valDbtn);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.valRadioGrupp);

    avsluta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.avslutaBtn);
    nasta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nastaBtn);
    pBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    cdText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterTxt);
}

private void setButtonListeners()
{
    // Nästaknapp onClick
    nasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            cd.cancel();            // Avslutar countdowntimer
            rattSvarCheck();        // Kontrollerar om svaret är rätt

            if (buttonRaknare > 17)
            {
                nasta.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.avsluta_selector));
            }

            if (buttonRaknare != 19)                            // Så länge det inte är sista frågan
            {
                buttonRaknare++;
                rg.clearCheck();                                // Tar bort check från valknapparna
                startCountdownTimer(totalMillis, false);        // Startar om den avslutade countdowntimer
                getNastaFragaData();                            // Tar nästa frågans innehåll till view
            }
            else if (buttonRaknare == 19)
            {
                resultatToDatabas();                            // Sparar resultaten till databasen
            }
        }
    });

    // Avslutaknapp onClick
    avsluta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            cd.cancel();                    // Pausar cooldowntimer först
            visaAlertDialog();              // Visar alert dialog
        }
    });
}
// Visa alertDialog
private void visaAlertDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder adBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Avsluta")
            .setMessage("Vill du avsluta quizet?")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)

            .setPositiveButton(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F616)) + " Japp! ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F60A)) + " Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    cd.cancel();
                    //RESUME COUNTDOWNTIMER
                    startCountdownTimer(millisLeft, true);
                }
            })

            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    cd.cancel();
                    //RESUME COUNTDOWNTIMER
                    startCountdownTimer(millisLeft, true);
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = adBuild.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void checkDB()
{
    try
    {
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException a) {
        a.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException b) {
        b.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_page);
        setViewElements();
        setButtonListeners();
        getNastaFragaData();
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_page);
        setViewElements();
        setButtonListeners();
        getNastaFragaData();
    }
}

// onBackPressed metod som visar alertDialog
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    cd.cancel();
    visaAlertDialog();
}

// onStop METHOD
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    dbHelper.close();
}
}
```

My quizpage layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/quizpage_bg"
    tools:context="com.example.onur.quiz.QuizPage">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1/20"
        android:id="@+id/pageNumberTxt"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ffab6200"
        android:background="@drawable/pagenumberbg"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/nastaBtn"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/nasta_selector"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/avslutaBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/exit_selector"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/valRadioGrupp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:divider="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nastaBtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/svarbg"  >


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="valAtxt"
            android:id="@+id/valAbtn"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_rg_drawer"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="valBbtn"
            android:id="@+id/valBbtn"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nastaBtn"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_rg_drawer"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="valCbtn"
            android:id="@+id/valCbtn"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_rg_drawer"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="valDbtn"
            android:id="@+id/valDbtn"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_rg_drawer"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hur många personer bor i Trollhättan?"
        android:id="@+id/fragaTxt"
        android:textColor="#ffc37800"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avslutaBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fragabg"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:progressDrawable = "@drawable/nypbar"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragaTxt" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="10.00"
        android:id="@+id/counterTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragaTxt"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has much to do with bitmaps, especially if you are pulling them from Drawable resources. The source of your lag is likely your database queries, which are happening in onCreate, which are blocking the main thread to do disk access. Instead, use a CursorLoader as described in https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have read about it now for 2 hours, looks pretty advanced for my level to understand the way it works. Most of the examples are with list adapters and different things, can't really put it to my project. Mostly because of my level.. Is there any other recommendations for me to look ahead to optimise it?

Comment: What you need to learn about is how to run code on a background thread instead of on the main thread. Any method like onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, and etc. are all called on the main thread, so you can't use them for long operations like disk or network access. If you don't want to use loaders to do this, you might find AsyncTask to be easier.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep reading loaders and asynctask :)